# Core Data Relationships

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

Supposing you had a data model that looks like:

```
/-----------------------\          /-----------------------\
| Patient               |          | Medication            |
|-----------------------|          |-----------------------|
| firstName             |          | startOn               |
| lastName              |          | endOn                 |
|-----------------------|          |-----------------------|
| medications           | <<-\     |                       |
|                       |     \->> | patients              |
\-----------------------/          \-----------------------/
```

So there is a many-to-many relationship: patients have many medications and a medication has many patients.

Given a `Patient` object, how would you get the related `Medication` with the most recent `endOn`?
(assumption: a patient does not have more than one medication that ends on the same date) i.e.:

```
// patientZero is a patient with related medication records
Patient *patientZero = ...;
Medication *mostRecentMed = [patientZero mostRecentlyCompletedMedication];
```

How would one implement the `mostRecentlyCompletedMedication` method?

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully patients do not have many medications, and medications do not have many patients. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not a Core Data question, but a Cocoa collections question. I would sort the `medications` association set. Assuming the Patient=>Medication to-many association is called `medications`:

```
Patient *myPatient;

NSSet *medications = [myPatient medications];
Medication *mostRecent = [medications sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"endOn" ascending:YES]]]
                           lastObject
                          ];
```

Comment: Holy mandingo!  Thank gosh I sprung for that cinema display!!! Seriously though thanks that clears things up greatly. Can't believe I didn't see this before.

Comment: @Bill You can easily break this up into more lines (Xcode's editor, like a good LISP editor will indent properly within a mess call), but it's a pain in the SO editor to line things up...